# Absolute minimum current drawn from a DC power supply

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, 555, current-source

I am using a Keithley PWS2721 DC supply to power an ICM7555 timer IC. The datasheet for the IC indicates a typical current draw between 30 - 250 µA (for a voltage range 2 - 16.5 V). The datasheet for the DC power supply indicates a current resolution of 10 mA.

What is the absolute minimum current that can be drawn from the power supply, considering that its resolution is much larger than the operating current range of the IC? I noticed that the timer output frequency increases as the DC voltage is ramped from 2 - 16.5 V, which is unclear considering that the formula for the frequency (astable mode)  (\$f=\frac{1.46}{[R_A+2R_B]C_1}\$) has no dependence on voltage. The formula agrees with the timer output frequency only for 2 V in my circuit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any typical DC power supply will have a minimum load current of 0 A.

There are exceptions, but usually only for power supplies for very specific loads. Not your general lab power supply.

The resolution of the ammeter on the supply has little to no correlation with any minimum load current of the supply.